# Intent a gmail no muestra datos precargados

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, mail

**Buenas. estoy tratando de abrir **Outlook** o **Gmail** desde un `Intent` en `Android`. Lo consigo, pero sucede que en **Outlook** me setea el **asunto/cuerpo del mensaje** como se lo digo. Pero, en **Gmail** no muestra esos datos que les paso. Lo estoy realizando de la siguiente forma:

```
public void  enviarEmail(Context context){
    Intent outlookEmail =  context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.microsoft.office.outlook");
    Intent gmailEmail = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");
    if (gmailEmail  != null && outlookEmail !=null) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto","mail@mail.com", null));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Asunto");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Cuerpo del mensaje");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar reporte: "));
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "No posees una aplicación para realizar esta acción.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Estas dos líneas en **Gmail** no muestran lo seteado:

```
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Asunto");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Cuerpo del mensaje");
```

¿Alguno me podría guiar en cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Y si el usuario no tienen ninguna de esas dos aplicaciones instaladas?

Comment: Pues, no puede mandar el email. Pero, esto es en entorno de pruebas. Luego se añadirán más aplicaciones para ello. Por el momento, estoy probando de hacerlo con esas aplicaciones @SuperG280

Comment: Y no sería más sencillo usar `Intent.createChooser` y que usuario seleccione la aplicación que quiera de las que tenga instaladas, sin que tú tengas que cambiar tu código?

Comment: Claramente, esa sería la opción más viable pero quiero hacer lo que digo @SuperG280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema con Gmail es que por seguridad no acepta se agregue automáticamente código HTML, por lo tanto lo que debes enviar es texto plano, definiendo:

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
```